# Storing Dropbox file content into variable with PHP

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I need you're help cause I'm stuck and Google doesn't offer any solution. I'm trying to read the content of a .txt file via official Dropbox API. It's working so far but it's not pretty in my eyes. There has to be an easy way for storing file content directly into an array/string variable.

What I got so far is a workaround with a temporary file on the webserver:

```
$tempFile = fopen("tempOnWebserver.txt", "w+");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/someFileOnDropbox.txt", $tempFile);
fclose($tempFile);
$fileContent = file_get_contents("tempOnWebserver.txt");
```

So I just want to write `$dbxClient->getFile("/someFileOnDropbox.txt", $fileContent)` and skip the workaround but that's - of course - not possible (: Is there any way to get this?

For Dropbox getFile function see http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_getFile.

Comment: I don't see any other way as the Dropbox SDK doesn't offer anything else than writing to a file.

Comment: The function is writing to something of type `resource` (usually a file). Isn't there a chance to create a variable of this type?

Comment: A ressource is a special variable with a reference to an external ressource. So nope, no chance. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: Too bad :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without actually writing to a file using a [`php://memory` stream](http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptios):

```
$stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
$dbxClient->getFile("/someFileOnDropbox.txt", $stream);
rewind($stream);
$fileContents = stream_get_contents($stream);
```

This does not really simplify your program, but at least to get by without writing any actual files on your server.

---

You could also extend the Dropbox `Client` class to encapsulate this functionality:

```
class YourClient extends \Dropbox\Client
{
    public function getFileContents($filename)
    {
        $stream = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
        $this->getFile("/someFileOnDropbox.txt", $stream);
        rewind($stream);
        $fileContents = stream_get_contents($stream);
        fclose($stream);
        return $fileContents;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for :) I'll try and make a report.

Comment: Had to alter the class by a constructor but now it works like a charm! Added `public function __construct($accessToken) { parent::__construct($accessToken, "ClientIdentifier"); }`